# How to center FontAwesome icon in css before content vertically

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am going crazy. I have read dozens of blog articles and different stackoverflow postings but I am unable to vertically center a FontAwesome icon which is placed as content inside a css before pseudo element of a link element.

This is my CSS Code:

```
a.button {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.button.forward {
    padding-right: 35px;
}

a.button.back {
    padding-left: 35px;
}

a.button.back:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f100";
    font-size: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
}
```

And thats the HTML code:

```
<a class="button back">back to<br/>whatever</a>
```

Here you can find a fiddle which shows my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/r1vysfaf/1

UPDATE:

I want to avoid using javascript to solve the styling issue. Furthermore the text of the link is dynamic and therefore it is not a solution to use "constant magic" spacings for paddings/margin/top.

Comment: You just want the icon centered and to the left within the button?

Comment: Thats right, The goal was to get it working only with css and without any other helper elements like spans inside the a element but maybe the most dynamic (maybe the only?) solution is exactly that: using helper elements?

Comment: Check my updated answer. ;)

Comment: @TobiasJ. I guess you can use helper elements?(IDK what that is). I just used CSS, see my answer. Just one change to your code and two adjustments that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table` for parent and `table-cell` for child and alter your css as following:

```css
a.button {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}

a.button.forward {
    padding-right: 35px;
}

a.button.back {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

a.button.back:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f100";
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <a class="button back">back to<br/>whatever</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to use magic constants. The text of the link is dynamic and can be longer or shorter. Therefore the line-height of 46px as you suggests only works right now.

Comment: Ok this is not an issue but that wasn't mentioned in your question. In order now to help you, are you ok to use js in your project?

Comment: I am using javascript right now but I really want to avoid javascript to solve such a styling issue.

Comment: Great. Veeery close to what I need. Is it possible to center the text vertically if the FontAwesome icon is bigger? Try to change font-size of the icon to 1.8em and remove the line-break in the text. The text of the link is now not centered vertically to the icon.

Comment: Based on your css the alignment happens with the padding on the `.forward `and `.back` classed. You can alter them to achieve your need.

Comment: Also I see that if I change the size of the font to 1.8em (or more) it is still centered ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128807/discussion-between-tobias-j-and-vassilis-pits).

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Added the forward button, plus position values in ems so an increase or decrease of font sizes or element will not offset the icon.

Instead of `absolute` , use `relative` on the pseudo-element.

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/8rr4ucbc/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```css
a.button {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.button.forward {
  padding-right: 35px;
}
a.button.back {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
a.button.back:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f100";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: .625em;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1.25em;
}
a.button.forward:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f101";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
  left: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<a class="button back">Back to<br/>whatever</a>
<a class="button back" style='font-size: 1.5em'>Font-size is<br/>increased by 50%</a>
<a class="button forward">Next to<br/>whatever</a>
<a class="button forward" style='font-size: .5em'>Font-size is<br/>decreased by 50%</a>
```